# jquery plugin for website annotation/tour?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Is there a jquery plugin that can mask and focus some html element step by step like a tutorial of the website?

Comment: you mean something like what facebook uses to introduce a new feature?

Comment: Look here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/ Hope that helps you

Comment: Checkout [Trip.js](http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/), [Intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/) or [Tourist.js](http://easelinc.github.io/tourist/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Jquery Guiders](https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS) is a good one.

Revaxarts provides an [excellent site tour plugin.](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tour-the-flexible-tour-plugin/1052564) (Paid/Not free)

If you dont like this then [jQuery Tools expose plugin](http://jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html) is all you need.

An other alternative can be [this](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin).

Comment: @Jurudocs - yep it really is cool :)

Comment: @fkingan - you're welcome to SO