# jQuery feature highlighter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I'm looking for something similar to the [jQuery Highlighter](http://blog.dreamcss.com/jquery-plugin/jquery-highlighter-easy-to-use-jquery-plugin-to-highlight-any-part-of-site/).

They recommend not using it in production since it is still in alpha, so I was wondering if there were any other alternatives that you guys have used and like.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now that I learned that "tour" is the keyword I should have used, here is some more that I found:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10361727/462158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of examples:

[drawium.com](http://drawium.com/) is free for beta users now, so it is not too late to use it without paying.
And [jQuery Joyride](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_joyride_feature_tour_plugin) is under the MIT license, and there is no need to hurry up.:)